# Mailing the GSP in Grails with the Mail plugin

Tags: email, plugins, grails, attachment, gsp

I´m sending an email with the [Mail Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail) for Grails of a GSP. In this GSP I have added images using ...

```
src="${resource(dir:'img', file:'line.jpg')}"
```

... for example but when I get the email the links seems like they are broken. I think it´s beacause the resources from the Grails project aren´t attached to the mail when this one is created.

Could it be anything else? What can I do to attach the resources files to the email with the plugin or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Grails' mail plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail) has [recently added a way to inline images](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMAIL-41) in 1.0 version.

`inline()` method must work - let me guess how the syntax should look:

```
mailService.sendMail {
    to m.email
    subject m.emailSubject
    body m.emailBody
    inline 'mylogo', new File(path)
}
```

where `mylogo` is resource id that should be referred in `m.emailBody` like:
`<img src="mylogo" />`

There was a [historical way on maillist](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Multipart-mail-embedded-images-in-the-mail-plugin-td1385475.html), but hopefully now you don't need to hack a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

src="${resource(dir:'img', file:'line.jpg', absolute: 'true')}"

Comment: ¿which function does the absolute attribute?

Comment: The question is about attaching images in mail plugin.

Comment: This is actually a good answer - with absolute paths you can load the images from your domain, and don't need to attach them to the mail.  This has advantages (smaller email) and disadvantages (slower image loadtime and dependence on your webserver) depending on your usecase